# the path defined in the route is not correct symfony

Tags: symfony, routes

I try to redirect to a route after the succes of my form..
In dev it works perfectly

my html:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="{{ path('homepage') }}" />
```

my router:

```
homepage:
    path: /homepage
    defaults: { _controller: 'App\Controller\HomePageController::hello' }
```

I am redirected to :

> http://localhost:8000/homepage

The problem is that in prod environment

I am redirected to:
https://mydomain.fr/mywebsite/public/mywebsite/public/homepage

What I have to do in prod to be redirected to 
https://mydomain.fr/mywebsite/public/homepage

For info I use the webserver provided by symfony in local
http://localhost:8000/

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Are you using Apache or NGINX? Please provide your web server configuration file. See Symfony Documentation on [Configuring a Web Server](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/setup/web_server_configuration.html) for your specific version of Symfony. You will need to change the document root to the location where your `app.php` file is located. The follow the [Deployment Guide](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/deployment.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put  your project in the same dir as public_html as a sibling. Then remove the public_html dir and recreate it as a symlink pointing to your project public dir. then make sure you install Apache-pack bundle it will create the .htaccess file and you should be good. Worked for me on A2host

Comment: Will try it.Thanks.